# Wix merge modules vc++ 9.0 SP1 not installing

Tags: visual-c++, wix, msvcrt

I have a Wix installer that I have added the merge modules to for the last version of the VC++ 9.0 runtime. I've opened the .msm files with Orca to verify that they are the latest version, 9.0.30729.6161. I include the CRT msm in my installer just as it is done in the example on the Wix site:

```
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
      <?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>
      <Merge Id="VCRedist" SourceFile="$(env.CommonProgramFiles)\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC90_CRT_x86_x64.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
      <?else?>
      <Merge Id="VCRedist" SourceFile="$(env.CommonProgramFiles)\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC90_CRT_x86.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
      <?endif ?>
    </DirectoryRef>    
</Fragment>
```

Then in my features file:

```
<MergeRef Id="VCRedist" />
```

When I run the installer with logging on, I can see that the files are moved to the side by side directory, C:\Windows\winsxs. When I run my application, it does not recognize that the CRT is available.

If I run the redistributable installer from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26368), everything works as expected. I've tried including all the merge modules with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the policy merge modules got it working for me.